# Where to get full list of registered ASN (autonomous system number)?

Tags: routes, ip, bgp

I need to maintain actual list of AS (autonomus system) include ASN and AS owner name.

There's some resource like ftp.arin.net/info/asn.txt or https://peeringdb.com/
But none of them contain full list of ASN. 
For example arin.net doesn't contain info about AS13238 and AS208722.
And peeringdb doesn't know about AS200350 (and doesn't have API anyway).

Is there an simple way to get **all** ASN and names of their owners (organizations)?

Answer (score 5):

TLDR;
Officially assigned ASNs are listed in

https://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/ripencc/nro-stats/latest/nro-delegated-stats

There is no such thing as universally official AS names; one of the attempts to provide AS names is published at

https://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/asnames/asn.txt

(but these aren't "names of their owners")  /TLDR;

---

The lists of officially assigned AS numbers are published by each of the RIRs on their ftp/websites, the canonical URLs are like this:

```
ftp://ftp.<rir>.net/pub/stats/<rir>/
```

where `<rir>` is one of `afrinic`, `apnic`, `arin`, `lacnic`, `ripencc`.

Most of these locations are also available over `https:` (but the host names still contain `ftp.`). And some RIRs mirror other's data, so you will find all data under `/pub/stats/` on the same site (but it might be slightly outdated).

[NRO](https://www.nro.net) combines all this data into single file:

https://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/ripencc/nro-stats/latest/nro-delegated-stats

so that you do not have to get 5 different files any more.

"AS names" are more difficult, and often do not contain "names of their owners (organizations)". RIRs do provide this info in their public databases, but it is registered differently and you would need to make several queries for each AS to get both the "AS name" and "AS owner name". [RDAP](https://www.apnic.net/about-apnic/whois_search/about/rdap/) unifies some aspects of these differences, but you would still need to query different servers with different URLs and paths.

There are several attempts to aggregate that info, for example:

https://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/asnames/asn.txt

https://bgp.potaroo.net/cidr/autnums.html

https://stat.ripe.net/docs/data_api#as-overview

Answer (score 4):

I found this [list](https://bgp.potaroo.net/cidr/autnums.html). It contains all ASN from your comment, but the list takes quite a while to load. Maybe it is useful to you, though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware this question is quite old at the time that I'm writing this, but RIPE maintains a publicly accessible (and more importantly **official**) list of all registered AS numbers, regardless of region, that is unlikely to ever go offline.

It can be accessed [here](https://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/asnames/asn.txt).

Be careful though, this list is not in the most well thought out format and may be hard to programmatically parse.

Answer (score 1):

Autonomous System numbers are being assigned by IANA, which globally
distribute these numbers between different regions.

In order to obtain an AS number, you first need to identify its region, then lookup
for it in the required region registry.

IANA region registries are specified here: https://www.iana.org/numbers